# How to mimic the item highlight behavior of NSTableView in NSCollectionView?

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, nscollectionview, nscollectionviewitem

I have `NSCollectionView` with custom items which contain `NSTextField` and `NSImageView`.

I realized highlight behavior of collection view items manually (ie. redefined the `setSelected:` method in my `NSCollectionViewItem` descendant class).
I successfully change the background color of selected items, but I miss one small but important thing: the text color of the selected item doesn't change.

I know that the `NSTableView` item highlighting changes the text color along with the background color, but I cannot mimic it since I don't know the algorithm of color's change.
The text color of my `NSCollectionViewItems` can be different. When I highlight the item in `NSTableView`, the gray text becomes lightgray, black becomes white and so on.
Does anybody know how they do that? Maybe there's a ready solution in the Cocoa API that I missed? Please help.